# Rerender AppNavigator on state change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, mobx-state-tree

I am trying to render certain  nav stacks depending on a `isAuthenticated` state. The problem that I am having is that `AppNavigator` is only rendered on the first render and not with any other changes and I am not sure why. I have tried a useEffect in the `AppNavigator` component to set a secondary local state with the callback being `isAuthenticated` but no go. I put everything pertinent below. I appreciate any advice.

I have an `AppNavigator` that is being rendered in my `app.tsx` file.

```
  return (
    <ToggleStorybook>
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <RootStoreProvider value={rootStore}>
          <SafeAreaProvider initialMetrics={initialWindowMetrics}>
            <ErrorBoundary catchErrors={"always"}>
              <AppNavigator
                initialState={initialNavigationState}
                onStateChange={onNavigationStateChange}
              />
            </ErrorBoundary>
          </SafeAreaProvider>
        </RootStoreProvider>
      </ApolloProvider>
    </ToggleStorybook>
  )
```

The `AppNavigator` is returning

```
export const AppNavigator = (props: NavigationProps) => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useStores()
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme()
  useBackButtonHandler(canExit)

  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      ref={navigationRef}
      theme={colorScheme === "dark" ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}
      {...props}
    >
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      >
        {isAuthenticated ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="main" component={MainTabs} />
        ) : (
          <Stack.Screen name="signup" component={SignUpStack} />
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

I am using mob-state-x-tree for state management and have a `setUser` action that is called `onAuthStateChanged` per the firebase Auth docs. I'm using email and password login and sign up. I've logged the auth state changes they are working as expected.

```
  function onAuthStateChanged(user: any) {
    if (user) {
      if (rootStore) {
        rootStore.setUser(user)
        console.log("we have passed user to root store")
      }
    }
```

The `setUser` action sets a state `isAuthenticated` in a `try` `catch`

```
  setUser: flow(function* (firebaseUser) {
    try {
      const idToken = yield firebaseUser.getIdToken()
      yield AsyncStorage.setItem(
        '@lessns:token',
        idToken
      );
      self.isAuthenticated = true
      self.user = {id: firebaseUser.uid}
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err, 'this is the first time ')
      self.isAuthenticated = false
    }
  }),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your `AppNavigator` component into an [`observer`](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/tree/main/packages/mobx-react-lite#observerpbasecomponent-functioncomponentp-functioncomponentp) so that it will re-render when observable data it depends on changes.

```js
export const AppNavigator = observer((props: NavigationProps) => {
  // ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

try to put AppNavigator component into an observer?

Comment: Thanks @S.Ozan! @Tholle recommended the same yesterday evening and it did work perfectly. I appreciate the feedback

Comment: nice thanks @Tholle